# WPF MVVM DataTrigger not getting invoked

Tags: wpf, combobox, devexpress

I have the following datatrigger attached to a combobox:

```
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Vendor:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,0,3"/>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding VendorList.Result}" 
                          DisplayMember="VendorName" ValueMember="VendorId" IsEnabled="False">                    
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbPogSetTypeList,
                         Path=EditValue}" 
                         Value="{x:Static data:PogStoreData+POGResetType.Vendor}">
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

In this trigger what I am trying to do is if "Vendor" is selected in the first combobox then the next combobox will become enabled. The first combobox is populated using an enum:

```
public enum POGResetType
        {
            Meijer=1,
            Vendor=2,
            Homestore=3
        }
```

But the second combobox is not getting enabled. Please help.

Comment: Can you please give some details on VendorList.Result? What type is it?

Answer (score 2):

Try referencing the enum value rather than the integer value.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cmbPogSetTypeList, Path=SelectedItem}"
Value="{x:Static mynamespace:POGResetType.Vendor}"/>
```

Comment: The enum POGResetType is inside a class POGStoreData. When I write POGStoreData.POGResetType.Vendor in Value, I am getting error nested types not allowed. Can you please help?

Comment: I changed my in accordance with your answer but it is still not working.

Comment: I have just realised that you are using DevExpress combo boxes. This changes things significantly as DevExpress controls have some unusual behaviour and many bugs that make them a lot more difficult to work with that the standard WPF controls. Have you tried binding to the EditValue property instead of SelectedItem?

Comment: It still did not help. I changed it to EditValue.

Comment: if an enum is inside of a class you should use `+` operator. i.e. `Class+Enum.value`

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a IValueConverter

```
<StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Planogram Set Type:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,0,3" />
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding PogSetTypeList}" Name="cmbPogSetTypeList"/>


            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Vendor:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,0,3"/>
            <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cmbPogSetTypeList,Path=SelectedItem,Converter={StaticResource Conv}}" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3"                                    >

            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

IvalueConverter

```
internal class ResetTypeConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                var revalue = (int)(POGResetType)value;
                if (revalue == 2)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```